# Which Programming methodology to used for Final Year Project?

Tags: methodology

I am a final year Computer Science Student and as part of my Bachelors degree I am doing a project on Data Mining of Microarray DNA expression data. I will have to develop a few algorithms such as Bayesian Networks to run on my datasets to find out how each variable(genes) affect each other.

As part of my Project Proposal I have to talk about which methodology I will use to develop my software.  From what I have learnt in school and from extra reading I find that the Incremental Development model seems a good idea. I would run 2- 3 iterations of Plan, Design, Implement until I get the full functionality of the software. Could somebody with more knowledge than me please tell me it this sounds like a good idea.

The reason why I am not 100% sure which methodology I would use is because I don't have a team to work on the software, I don't have a client with requirements and I am very limited in terms of the amount of time to work on the project as I have 3 other modules. All the methodologies which I have read about seem to be for big software projects with teams of developers. What do you do if you are just 1 person and focusing mainly on getting 3-4 algorithms to work rather than focusing on getting broad range of functionality.

I was also thinking of using UML to get a better idea what I want the software to do and using like a stripped down version of an Object Oriented Methodology.

My guess would be I would have to use parts of more than 1 methodology at a very basic level but I just can't pick.

I am very confused and lost on the subject so  any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these types of work, I would suggest not to pay much of attention to methodologies, because after all, what matters is the algorithm. But, for the sake of having a response for your dilemma, I would suggest using XP (eXtreme Programming). Why?

- Is light
- It doesn't require filling many papers as RUP & others
- Is more suited for changing evironments, such as yours

Just take a fast search at Google for XP methodology and you'll get a bunch of useful results. ARUP (Agile RUP) might be worth looking also.

I hope I can help you.

Comment: Hi David, I agree with you. I think I will write on my proposal that I will use some of the Agile development ideas and specifically the XP methodology more than others. I feel my main focus when choosing to develop in an area where you are not very knowledgable would have to be flexibility. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

XP/TDD is harmonious with the scientific method; each iteration is a theory, the tests are experiments

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. you all have helped me in making my decisions clearer and based on reasoning.

Comment: I like your view point Steven. Will think about it different now.. :)

Answer (score 1):

It takes a **lot** of discipline to follow a methodology while working solo, make sure you pick one that isn't labour intensive or you'll never live up to it.

If I was back at school in your situation with what I know now I'd probably go for Test Driven Development. Unit tests are ideal for testing algorithms and will leave you with a body of tests that you can use to demonstrate that you did follow a methodology.

Comment: Hi mate, Thanks. I kind of like the idea behind Extreme Programming. I think it will allow me more flexibility to play around because essentially I don't know where my project is going to end up for two main reasons: Not enough experience of working on software development projects and Not enough knowledge of the subject area. As I gain more  knowledge I will most probably change some requirements. I like the Test Drive approach as I will be able to test things and see results qucker.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to do the project in several iterations of plan, design, code and test is fine however with small projects it's sometimes difficult to resist the urge to do it all at once.

In case you do get carried away and finish the project in just one or two iterations, keep notes about the order in which you did things (ideally use a version control system) so that you'll at least be able to fudge your documentation to make it look like you used several iterations. Not that I'd endorse such an approach of course ;-)

Comment: Hi LachlanG, Once again thanks for the reply.  As I said on the original post it would probably be a use of different aspects of different methodologies. What I am getting from this whole discussion seems to be that for small individual projects it would be a good idea to go for a method which allows for changes to be made throughout the lifecycle.